# Extending HTML <a> tag elements in React and TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, htmlelements

I am using typescript in a React project and I want to add tag's props. I can access the properties of the `link` element but not the properties `a` element. I am getting an error when the properties of the `link` tag use an `a` tag.

Is there an 'HTMLAElement' structure for an element `a` in React?

```
const MyComponent: FunctionComponent<React.LinkHTMLAttributes<HTMLLinkElement>> = (
props: React.LinkHTMLAttributes<HTMLLinkElement>,
) => {
  return (
      <a {...props} className="mycomponent">  // When I use it with the <link> it doesn't give an error but I need <a>.
         MyComponent
      </a>
  );
};
```

Comment: Have a look at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement

Comment: I'm afraid it's not clear what you're asking here. Maybe you could get a colleague to help you write the question? But regarding *"I could not see an 'HTMLAElement' structure"*: The type of an `a` element is [`HTMLAnchorElement`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#htmlanchorelement). You can find those types in [this list](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/indices.html#elements-3) in the HTML5 specification.

Comment: Thank you      . I did not know that the element 'a' corresponds to 'anchor'. my shame 

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My problem is solved. Errors disappeared when I used 'HTMLAnchorElement'. I did not know that the element 'a' corresponds to 'anchor'.